# Does underscore not count as a non alphanumerical character in python?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

x = "dkvn_i45"

if re.search(r"\W", x):
  print("Yes")
else: 
  print("No")

>>> No
```

I'm confused as underscore is neither a number or a letter, so surely it would count as a non-alphanumerical character?

Comment: `\W` doesn't mean "non-alphanumerical character".

Comment: `\W` is the complement of [`\w`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-32), which is documented as matching "alphanumeric" characters for `bytes` values, but you have to realize that "alphanumeric" here includes `_`. `\w` really matches *word* characters, namely whatever can appear in traditional C-like identifier names. The definition of `\w` for `str` values is less misleading, as it doesn't use the term "alphanumeric".

Answer (score 1):

Docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

> `\W`
>   Matches any character which is not a word character. This is the opposite of `\w`. If the ASCII flag is used this becomes the equivalent of `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If the LOCALE flag is used, matches characters which are neither alphanumeric in the current locale nor the underscore.

(In short: no, `\W` does not match on `_`)

Answer (score 0):

In regex `\W` stands for any Non-Word character. 
Where **Non - Word Character** = `anything other than letter, digit or underscore`.

From above statement it should also be clear that underscore is clearly treated as a alphanumeric character.